# K/b and mouse work on Ubuntu 17.10 Live but not when on HDD

Tags: keyboard, 17.10, mouse, gui, .desktop

Title says it all really. I'm trying to install Ubuntu 17.10 on my HP Gen8 Microserver. When I boot Ubuntu Live the mouse, keyboard, in fact everything seems to work OK.

No matter how I install the software to my 250Gb HDD the resulting system has keyboard the won't accept key presses faster than about one a second and a mouse that's to all intents and purposes unresponsive. As yet, I've not been able to login!

I've tried installing the server edition and then the Ubuntu desktop on top; again, sluggish keyboard and unresponsive mouse.

What's the difference between the Live version and the installed version? How can I proceed.

---

OK. Just tried the Ubuntu Server install again. I've observed that the keyboard works perfectly on the command line - that is, I can type a whole lot faster than one key press a second. I can't check mouse support though! I then installed the Ubuntu standard desktop. Thence forth, clunky keyboard and sloth-like mouse. Now, unless someone knows different, I doubt that installing the Ubuntu desktop installed a different low-level keyboard driver I can only conclude that Ubuntu GUI support is flaky. What test can I do to help developers identify and fix this once and for all.

Alternatively, is there another GUI I can use that might avoid flaky keyboard and mouse support in the Ubuntu Standard desktop. Regards

---

Just tried xfce. Worked like a charm. My conclusion? Ubuntu Desktop is broke. If others are getting exasperated with Ubuntu Desktop, try xfce. Your mileage may vary but it's got to be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

This will be tough to answer without more specifics, but usually these problems are caused by drivers not being available to the kernel *after* the install. For example, you might want to do the following during the install:

1. Enable the option to download needed upgrade packages during the install.
2. Enable the option to install proprietary drivers.

That usually fixes it, unless the problem is actually being caused by you already enabling #1 above. In other words, in rare cases a newer driver downloaded during the installation can cause what you describe.

If that doesn't work, we'll need much more info to actually help.